# How to trap INT signal infinitely many times?

Tags: bash, signals, trap, interactive

I'm piping output of an interactive command (ghci) through sed-based script to add some colors:

```
ghci | colorize.sh
```

where `colorize.sh` is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' INT
sed '...some pattern...'
```

Now if I hit Ctrl-C I want only ghci to receive it (it does not terminate), and I want sed to thrive (or perhaps get restarted?) and still process the output of ghci.

This script does not work and I don't know why.

Comment: I forgot to add: the script does not work likely because it captures only the first SIGINT

Comment: What makes you think the script captures only the first SIGINT?

Comment: I can't reproduce it... Why do you think you're not getting the signal more than once? Can you check with `ps` and see that `sed` was indeed interrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me start out by saying that this doesn't answer your question, but I hope might help clarify what's happening.  I suspect that what you think is happening might not really be happening.  Consider this simple example:

```
# The 'writer' reads input from standard input and
# echos it to standard output.  It handles SIGINT by
# printing INT to standard output.
$ cat writer
#!/bin/bash
function foo() {
    echo "INT"
}

trap foo INT

while read x; do echo $x; done

# The 'reader' reads input from standard input and pipes what is
# read to 'sed', which converts it to upper case.  It ignores SIGINT.
# When it receives EOF on standard input, it writes "done".
$ cat reader
#!/bin/bash
trap '' INT
cat | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'
echo "done"
```

Now, when I run both, piping the output of `writer` into `reader`:

```
$ ./writer | ./reader
hello
HELLO
^CINT
^CINT
^CINT
world
WORLD
^D
done
$
```

The `writer` script reads reads from standard input and writes to the standard output – the pipe.  The `reader` scripts reads from standard input — the pipe — and writes to standard output.  When I hit `Ctrl-C`, the `writer` writes "INT"; the `reader` ignores the signal (multiple times).  Eventually, I enter `Ctrl-D` (EOF), and the `writer` terminates.  When the `reader` receives the EOF, it terminates and writes "done".

Note that the `reader` ignores the SIGINT more than once, and that neither the pipe nor `sed` is interrupted when the `writer` handles the SIGINT.

Comment: Your script works indeed the way we would expect. If I modify it with my sed expression: `while read x; do echo "$x" | sed "..."; done`, that works too as far as SIGINT is concerned. I can't use read because the prompt of ghci does not end with a newline. I'm curious why sed gets killed in my original script.

Comment: This script `trap '' INT; while true; do sed "$sedAll"; done` seems to be a good solution. I'm happy sed is not stateful. I still would like to understand why sed sees the SIGINT

Comment: I was too quick to say that this works, obviously it never exits which is problematic.

Comment: I updated the reader to use `sed`; `sed` is not interrupted by the signal.

Comment: And my example does exit on EOF (i.e., `Ctrl-D`).